# pytest function for setting pass status

Tags: pytest

is there in pytest an equivalent function for succeeded status like `pytest.skip` or `pytest.fail`?

Scenario:

```
def subf()_:
 ...  
 if p=="OK": pytest.pass???();

def test_AA001():
  ...   
  subf(p)
  a = 1
  assert a==0, "Oh noh"
```

(I don't want to return a variable to test_AA001)

Rr

Comment: Test will succeed if it doesn't fail or xfail or skip; no need to pass it explicitly.

Comment: That's clear. But in my example, in subf, how to stop the test with "PASS" status? I don't want to return a flag in subf towards test_AA0001 and skip the remaining code

Comment: By calling `return` without parameters?

Comment: Your idea is, in test_AA001: if not dubf(p): return;     I want to handle this instead in subf because I have hundreds of tests and I don't want to modify them all

Comment: No, `if p == "OK": return` in `subf()`.

Comment: Ok. I modified my code in order to make clearer my problem. Your solution in this case should not work...